# calling javascript in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

I am calling a javascript in the `onclick` event in ASP.NET sourcecode, as follows:

```
onclick='open popuplistitems("ct100$contentplaceholder..........")
```

Can you tell me how to do the same in vb.net ?

Comment: What is the difference between "asp.net source code" and VB.NET ? Is your source in C# ? If so, use an online converter.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the call to an attribute of a control.

Example:

Create a Label in your Forms designer.

In Webform1's constructor OR in the Page_Load method:

`Label.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.alert('done by vb')")`

At runtime, clicking on the label will execute the javascript call.